# to implement a kind of watchdog with inet

Tags: omnet++, inet

I am wondering how to monitor a node in manet that whether it forwards data packets or not?
The monitoring node works as a watchdog.
My objective is to detect selfish nodes (refuse to forward packets) in a distrubited manner.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you precise what do you mean by _monitor a node_? Could you edit your question and describe your network?

Comment: My network is a typical MANET. "monitor" means that nodes observe the behaviors of the node in interests. I don't know how to get some information, such as how many packets does it forward, about the node being observed.

Comment: Could you show the NED file of your network?